# Sorting contacts in alphabetical order in React-Native

Tags: react-native

Currently I'm working on a mobile app. I need to pull contacts from my phone into the app I'm creating (I use expo contacts). For some reason, instead of contacts being sorted in the alphabetical order, they show up in the random order.

I'm not quite sure how to sort the contacts to display them in the alphabetical order.

Can anyone please take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong/what I should add?

The code that I use:

```
// load contacts from phone

_loadContacts = async () => {
    try {
      await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CONTACTS);
      const { data: contacts } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({ fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers] })


 // for rendering contacts 

  _renderContact = ({ item: { firstName, lastName, name, phoneNumbers } }) => (
    <View style={styles.contact}>
      <Text style={styles.contactName}>{name || [firstName, lastName].join(" ")}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.phoneNumbers}> {phoneNumbers ? phoneNumbers.map(entry => entry.number).join(", ") : "undefined"}</Text>
    </View>
  )
```

Comment: What is the structure of contacts data ??

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to sort contacts using Expo. It was added in August 2018.  https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/sorting-options-for-contacts

If you check the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/contacts/) you can see that `getContactsAsync` takes a `ContactQuery`.

`ContactQuery` (see [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/contacts/#contactquery)) takes a `SortType` (see [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/contacts/#sorttype)), allowing you to sort the contacts by either FirstName or LastName.

A simple example would be the following.

```
 const { data: contacts } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({ 
    fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers], 
    sort: Contacts.SortTypes.FirstName 
 });
```

It is worth noting that at the current time, `SortType` is **only** available for Android. So for iOS you would need to sort them in the order you want, yourself.